# Unable to scrape the right wikitable with BeautifulSoup4 (beginner)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, datatable, wikipedia

A complete beginner here...I am trying to scrape the constituents table from this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTSE_Bursa_Malaysia_KLCI), however the table scraped was the annual returns (1st table) instead of the constituents table (2nd table) that I need. Could someone help to see if there is any way that i can target the specific table that i want using BeautifulSoup4?

```
import bs4 as bs
import pickle
import requests

def save_klci_tickers():
    resp = requests.get ('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTSE_Bursa_Malaysia_KLCI')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
    table = soup.find ('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll ('tr') [1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll ('td') [0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)

    with open ("klcitickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump (tickers, f)

    print (tickers)
    return tickers


save_klci_tickers()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pandas library to get the tabular data from that page in a csv file with the blink of an eye:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTSE_Bursa_Malaysia_KLCI'

df = pd.read_html(url, attrs={"class": "wikitable"})[1] #change the index to get the table you need from that page
new = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=["Constituent Name", "Stock Code", "Sector"])
new.to_csv("wiki_data.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

If it is still BeautifulSoup you wanna stick with, the following should serve the purpose:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTSE_Bursa_Malaysia_KLCI")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select("table.wikitable")[1].select("tr"):
    data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("th,td")]
    print(data)
```

If you wanna use `.find_all()` instead of `.select()`, try the following:

```
for items in soup.find_all("table",class_="wikitable")[1].find_all("tr"):
    data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all(["th","td"])]
    print(data)
```

Comment: thanks sir! I edited the code with the indexing you used as follows and it worked:

table = soup.select ('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'}) [2]

Thanks a lot my man!